# "An unexpected error has occurred" error on accessing PWA (Project Web Access)

Tags: sharepoint-2007, project-server, project-server-2007

I installed Microsoft Office Sharepoint 2007 SP1 using SQL Server 2008 R2 for DB and then installed Microsoft Office Project Server 2007.

I made a web application to host the SSP and another one to host the PWA (Project Web Access) and the PWA was provisioned as: "http://server/pwa"

when i click on this link it gives me an error "An unexpected error has occurred"

i tried to restart the project service and to iisreset but it wasn't solved..

I need to finish this ASAP for our administration :-/

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2003 R2 x86

Comment: i searched for a solution as well , didnt find any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

I had to change the following in web.config :

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="off" />
```

and:

```
<configuration>
<SharePoint>
<SafeMode CallStack="true"
```

Then the problem appeared to be about the Proxy authentication and i solved it by adding the following inside System.Net

```
 <defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault = "true" bypassonlocal = "true" />
 </defaultProxy>
```

and make sure ur IE proxy settings are correct ..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks your Solution fixed by issue also , but i has another solution for that ,
you can go to Central Application --> Web Applications Management -->Select your Web Application and then select in the top Ribbon "Web Applications" Option and Click Service Connections then Check "Connects to YOUR PROJECT INSTANCE NAME" and Click Ok.